# How do you map a Mac keyboard to PC layout?

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

Say I have a Mac keyboard and want to use it on a PC. Some of the keys aren't quite right. How do I map them correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problems with using an Apple keyboard on a PC are as follows:

- Media & Volume keys are nonfunctional
- Command key where Alt key should be, but acts like Windows key
- Option key where Windows key should be, but acts like Alt key
- Right Control key acts like Right Alt key
- Fn key where Insert key should be (wired keyboard only)
- Clear key where NumLock key should be (wired keyboard only)

You can use scancode mapping to map the F7-F12 scancodes to the Windows media keyboard equivalents, turn F13-F15 into the PrintScreen, Scroll Lock, and Pause keys, and make the Ctrl and Alt keys work properly.  After that you hit a wall with scancode mapping.

Instead, install [uawks](http://code.google.com/p/uawks/).   Its a little program that uses [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) scripts to map your Mac keyboard keys to the PC equivalents.  You can always tweak the scripts to get the exact behavior you want.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following to swap the alt and command/Windows keys.  Paste into a .reg file, then run it to import into your registry.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,08,00,00,00,37,e0,64,00,5b,e0,38,00,\
  38,00,5b,e0,5c,e0,38,e0,38,e0,5c,e0,47,e0,63,e0,0d,00,59,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: How do you remove this after its been added?

Comment: @Marc At least on the Windows 7 machine I'm on now, the "Scancode Map" value doesn't exist by default, so simply deleting it will probably do it. Though, I suggest you export the key first just in case something goes wrong (right-click "Keyboard Layout" and choose "Export").

Comment: I did that right after I typed this, simply deleting the key sorted me out!  Thanks Stephen.

Answer (score 0):

**Only for Portuguese layout**, here is the solution:

https://www.outsystems.com/forums/discussion/15527/portuguese-keyboard-layout-for-windows-vm-running-on-a-mac/